# Python: display the number of one's in any user given integer number

Tags: python

How do I display the number of one's in any given integer number?

I am very new to python so keep this in mind.

I need the user to input a whole number.

Then I want it to spit out how many one's are in the number they input.

i am using python 3.3.4

How would I be able to do this with this following code?

```
num = int(input ("Input a number containing more than 2 digits"))
count = 0
for i in range (0):
    if num(i) == "1":
        count = count + 1

print (count)
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong
it gives me 'int' object is not callable error

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

str(num).count('1') works just fine, but if you're just learning python and want to code your own program to do it, I'd use something like this, but you're on the right track with the code you supplied:

```
count = 0
for i in str(num):
    if i == "1":
        count = count + 1 # or count += 1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

Int is not iterable so you may need to convert into string:

```
>>> num = 1231112
>>> str(num).count('1')
4
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to help you, here is a function that will print out each digit right to left.

```
def count_ones(num):
  while num:
    print(num % 10) # last digit
    num //= 10 # get rid of last digit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = 1112111
answer = str(num).count("1")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = int(input (" Input a number to have the number of ones be counted "))
count = 0
   for i in str(num):
   if i == "1":
       count = count + 1 # or count += 1
print (' The number of ones you have is ' + str(count))
```

So i took the user input and added it to the correct answer since when i tried the answer from crclayton it didn't work. So this works for me.